# How to solve multivariate equation systems programmatically?

Tags: java, wolfram-mathematica, sympy, equation-solving, symja

I am trying to solve a system of multivariate equations, which are the result of some Java code. Neither the form, nor the number of variables is known before runtime. An example would be

```
(I) (e-a*d*e-b*d*e+2*b*d*f+2*b*d*e*g)/(-1+a*d+b*d)+f == 0

(II) e*g+((f+e*g)*a*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d)==0

(III) -e*h+((-f-e*g)*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d)==0

(IV) -e*j+((-f-e*g)*c)/(-1+a*d+b*d)==0
```

I tried using [Symja](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/Home), which simply returns the input, and [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), which throws an Error

```
ZeroDivisionError: polynomial division
```

The variables are all from the interval [0,1], and I need all solutions. Mathematica is able to solve this, but as it is commercial software I unfortunately cannot use it in this project.

I would be grateful for any recommendations on which software to use. I really would have liked SymPy to work, and I don't understand why it throws this error, ideas are appreciated. Below a MWE to the SymPy Error:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.abc import a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j

lst = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j
sys = [(e-a*d*e-b*d*e+2*b*d*f+2*b*d*e*g)/(-1+a*d+b*d)+f,e*g+((f+e*g)*a*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d),-e*h+((-f-e*g)*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d),-e*j+((-f-e*g)*c)/(-1+a*d+b*d)]

solution = solve(sys, lst)
print solution
```

The Mathematica version is:

```
eqn = {(e - a*d*e - b*d*e + 2*b*d*f + 2*b*d*e*g)/(-1 + a*d + b*d) + f == 0, e*g + ((f + e*g)*a*d)/(-1 + a*d + b*d) == 0, -e*h + ((-f - e*g)*d)/(-1 + a*d + b*d) == 0, -e*j + ((-f - e*g)*c)/(-1 + a*d + b*d) == 0};
Simplify[Solve[eqn, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j}]]
```

Output:

```
{{e -> 0, f -> 0},
{c -> (1 - 2 a d - 3 b d) j, f -> ((-1 + 2 a d + b d) e)/(-1 + 2 a d + 3 b d), g -> (a d)/(1 - 2 a d - 3 b d), h -> d/(1 - 2 a d - 3 b d)},
{a -> 0, c -> j - 3 b d j, f -> ((-1 + b d) e)/(-1 + 3 b d), g -> 0, h -> d/(1 - 3 b d)},
{a -> (1 - b d)/(2 d), c -> -2 b d j, f -> 0, g -> 1/4 - 1/(4 b d), h -> -(1/(2 b))}}
```

Comment: Can you post the Mathematica expression and solution?

Comment: have you tried multiplying out the common denominator? I'd guess those tools give ways to automate that but you might do it by hand to see if they can solve the result.

Comment: @agentp Yes I tried that, and it doesn't help, SymPy still throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve the problem myself using SAGE, with gives the same output as Mathematica.

```
sage: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j = var('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j')
sage: qe = [(e-a*d*e-b*d*e+2*b*d*f+2*b*d*e*g)+f*(-1+a*d+b*d),e*g*(-1+a*d+b*d)+((f+e*g)*a*d),-e*h*(-1+a*d+b*d)+((-f-e*g)*d),-e*j*(-1+a*d+b*d)+((-f-e*g)*c)]
sage: print(solve(qe,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j, solution_dict=True))
```

Gives the output

```
[{g: r5, j: r7, b: r2, d: r4, e: 0, h: r6, c: r3, f: 0, a: r1},
{g: r12, j: r14, b: r8, d: r10, e: r11, h: r13, c: r9, f: -r11*r12, a: -(r10*r8 - 1)/r10},
{g: r15*r18, j: r19, b: -1/6*(4*r15*r16*r18 - r16 + 3*r17)*(4*r15*r16*r18^2/(4*r15*r16*r18 - r16 + 3*r17) + 2*r16*r18/(4*r15*r16*r18 - r16 + 3*r17) - r18)/(r16*r18^2), d: 2*r16*r18/(4*r15*r16*r18 - r16 + 3*r17), e: r16, h: r18, c: 2*r16*r19/(4*r15*r16*r18 - r16 + 3*r17), f: r17, a: r15},
{g: r20*r23, j: 0, b: -1/6*(4*r20*r21*r23 - r21 + 3*r22)*(4*r20*r21*r23^2/(4*r20*r21*r23 - r21 + 3*r22) + 2*r21*r23/(4*r20*r21*r23 - r21 + 3*r22) - r23)/(r21*r23^2), d: 2*r21*r23/(4*r20*r21*r23 - r21 + 3*r22), e: r21, h: r23, c: 0, f: r22, a: r20},
{g: -2*r24*r27 - 1, j: 0, b: r24, d: r25, e: r26, h: r27, c: 0, f: 2*r24*r26*r27 + r26, a: -(r24*r25 - 1)/r25},
{g: 0, j: r30, b: r29, d: 0, e: r31, h: 0, c: r30, f: r31, a: r28},
{g: 0, j: 0, b: r33, d: 0, e: r34, h: 0, c: 0, f: r34, a: r32},
{g: -1, j: 0, b: 0, d: r35, e: r36, h: r37, c: 0, f: r36, a: 1/r35},
{g: r40, j: 0, b: 0, d: r38, e: r39, h: 2*r38*r40 + r38, c: 0, f: r39, a: r40/(2*r38*r40 + r38)},
{g: -1/2, j: 0, b: -1/2*(r41 - r42)/(r41*r43), d: -2/3*r41*r43/(r41 - r42), e: r41, h: r43, c: 0, f: r42, a: -1/2/r43}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have 9 variables and 4 equations. Hence, you can eliminate four variables - you need to tell Sympy which.

The following code first multiplies the denominator out and the eliminates `a,b,c,d`:

```
import sympy as sy
from IPython.display import display  # for pretty printing

# sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX-like pretty printing for IPython

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j = sy.symbols("a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j", real=True)
lst = a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j
sys0 = sy.Matrix([(e-a*d*e-b*d*e+2*b*d*f+2*b*d*e*g)/(-1+a*d+b*d)+f,
                  e*g+((f+e*g)*a*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d),
                  -e*h+((-f-e*g)*d)/(-1+a*d+b*d),
                  -e*j+((-f-e*g)*c)/(-1+a*d+b*d)])

# Denominator can be factored out:
den = a*d + b*d - 1
sys1 = sy.simplify(sys0*den).expand()
print("Factored out denominator:")
display(sys1)

# Elimnate four variables:
sol1 = sy.solve(sys1, a, b, c, d, dict=True)
print("Solutions:")
display(sol1)
print("Substituting back into the equation gives obviously 0, i.e.:")
display(sy.simplify(sys1.subs(sol1[0])).T)

print("The denominator != 0 results in:")
den1 = sy.simplify(den.subs(sol1[0]))
display(sy.solve(den1))
```

which generates the following output:

```
Factored out denominator:
Matrix([
[-a*d*e + a*d*f + 2*b*d*e*g - b*d*e + 3*b*d*f + e - f],
[                   2*a*d*e*g + a*d*f + b*d*e*g - e*g],
[              -a*d*e*h - b*d*e*h - d*e*g - d*f + e*h],
[              -a*d*e*j - b*d*e*j - c*e*g - c*f + e*j]])
Solutions:
[{d: 2*e*h/(4*e*g - e + 3*f),
  c: 2*e*j/(4*e*g - e + 3*f),
  a: g/h,
  b: (-e + f)/(2*e*h)}]
Substituting back into the equation gives obviously 0, i.e.:
Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0]])
The denominator != 0 results in:
[{e: -f/g}]
```

So the resulting identities are:

```
-f/g != e  # denominator - only false, if f,e=0 since f,g,e>=0
a = g/h
b = (-e + f)/(2*e*h)
c = 2*e*j/(4*e*g - e + 3*f)
d = 2*e*h/(4*e*g - e + 3*f)
```

As far as I'm aware, Sympy cannot handle multivariate inequalities yet (though I would like to be proven wrong). But the results are simple enough to do by hand:

```
 0 <= g <= h
 0 <= f-e <= 2*e*h
 0 <= 2*e*j <= 4*e*g - e + 3*f
 0 <= 2*e*h <= 4*e*g - e + 3*f
 0 <= e,f,g,h,j <= 1
```

The case `f,e=0` is valid as well. It can be verified by checking that `sys0.subs(e,0).diff(f)` does not depend on `f`.

Comment: very nice approach.

Comment: That is indeed a nice approach for this particular system. Unfortunately, the structure of the equations are not known before runtime. That means that this case of all equations having a common denominator is an artifact, and may be different in other cases. Thus I do not see how this solution can be extended to work programmatically.

Comment: @berndibus If you know nothing or little about the structure of your equations, in my experience such an approach is problematic (especially for the corner cases). In Mathematica (and also Sympy), I routinely wait  half an hour and more to see if `Solve[]` comes up with a valid solution or not . Note that Mathematica does not give *all* solutions in your example - `Reduce[]` would be more appropriate. If you're sure, you're equations are well behaved, your 80% solution might be to eliminate the first four variables as I done in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case this question gets closed, here is an attempt at the Mathematica version.  However it currently lacks conditions restricting the variables to the interval [0,1].

```
Solve[{
  (e - a d e - b d e + 2 b d f + 2 b d e g)/(-1 + a d + b d) + f == 0,
   e g + ((f + e g) a d)/(-1 + a d + b d) == 0,
  -e h + ((-f - e g) d)/(-1 + a d + b d) == 0,
  -e j + ((-f - e g) c)/(-1 + a d + b d) == 0
  },
 {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have added the Mathematica version I have to my question, but I cannot use Mathematica for my problem as it is commercial software.

Comment: You have not added any conditions that would limit the variables to the interval [0,1] so guess that is not primarily relevant to what you require from SymPy (or other software).

Comment: It would be nice, but I thought it would be possible to restrict that in a second step, the main task is the solving. If it is possible to do that directly, it would be much better.